# c string still works when out of boundary?

Tags: c, arrays, string, printf

who can tell me why the code below still works? it is obvious that the str[4] is out of boundry:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char str[3];
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("%c\n", str[4]);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

when it runs, enter `abcdefg`, it will echo the 5th char and the whole string, nothing
will be wrong, weird?

It has been declared that c/c++ doesn't do the boundary checking, while in the case above,
how should I use printf to print a c-string that the user has entered? or more generally, how to properly use a c-string that comes from users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

str[4] gives you a pointer to the memory address after the last element of your string. You can still convert this to a character, but you never know what you get and your software might crash.

Comment: Yes, it has been declared that c/c++ doesn't do the boundary checking, while in the case above, how should I use printf to print a c-string that the user has entered? or more generally, how to properly use a c-string that comes from users?

Comment: I think scanf is in general kind of dangerous as it does not prevent buffer overflows as you illustrate in your example. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf for a discussion about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it work?

It doesn't "work". It might *appear to be working,* though; since your code (accessing an array out of bounds) invokes undefined behavior, you can get literally any result. Undefined behavior doesn't mean "it must crash".

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> when it runs, enter [abcdefg], it will echo the 5th char and the whole
>   string, nothing will be wrong, weird?

but I see no input reading in the code you posted:

> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> int main(){
>     char str[3];
>     printf("%c\n", str[4]);
>     printf("%s\n", str);
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

In any case, `str[4]` points to the 5-th `char` (byte) starting from `str`, so it will print any "garbage" that happens to be in that memory location when your program runs.

Accessing array items out of bounds is *undefined* behavior, so the exact behavior is not specified.
Just pay attention to your array bounds.

Comment: Oh, I removed that line by mistake, it's been added now. another question: how should I properly use( like `printf("%s",str)`) a c-string that comes from user?